# SSH Reverse tunnel assistance with application

Tags: ssh, nat, tunnel, dvr, reverse-tunnel

Well it does in a way. If I do something like:

`ssh -R 27011:localhost:25566 USER@NAME.COM -p 27010`
NOTE: substituting the real username and domain with USER@NAME.COM for security.
NOTE: The port for the middleman ssh server is 27010(must be used to establish ANY SSH connection to middleman), the port for the ssh server behind the NAT on its local network is 25566(only matters if just forwarding ssh access to remote server)
I'm able to login to the server behind the NAT by first SSH into the middleman (NAME.COM port 27010) then doing:
`ssh user@localhost -p 27011`

then I'm in the server behind the NAT and can control it from command line.

Here's the issue -
I have a Lorex camera system. The ports are: 25560 for media/video, 25561 for web/http, and 25562 for mobile. I've tried every command that I could come up with and could not login to it via the client (allows you to put in IP and port then user and password).

IP to the Lorex system (static/local): 192.168.1.5

The command that I've tried:
`ssh -R 27013:192.168.1.5:25560 -R 27014:192.168.1.5:25561 user@name.com -p 27010`

The software is only available on Windows, so I must use PuTTY to SSH tunnel. Basically I'm trying to use the middleman to give me access to the network behind the NAT by reverse tunnel from the remove server, and use the Lorex client software on Windows to connect to the Lorex DVR.

ME--------->MIDDLEMAN<---------REMOTE SERVER

LOREXCLIENT--------->---MIDDLEMAN--------->REMOTE SERVER/NETWORK/LOREXDVR
(I want the Lorex client to go through the middleman (can't port forward the remote server, obviously.) to get to the remote server to allow me access to the DVR.)

*Clarification:*
I'm on a WISP and am unable to port forward through the jungle of NATs not to mention that I don't have access to them. I've tried contacting the administrator of them; however, he's not the easiest with whom I can get in touch. He's the only one that controls the equipment. Because I'm unable to port forward the Lorex DVR myself, I'm trying to use a reverse tunnel through a server that I do have the ability to port forward, which is at a relative's house. The computer I'm planning to use to view the cameras is not the same middleman server, and it will not be on the same connection at all times. I understand that it could work from the middleman server itself; however, since that server doesn't run Windows, which the client software requires and will not run in Wine, I'm wanting to use, say a laptop, to connect to the middleman server with a tunnel, not in reverse if possible, using PuTTY and putting the appropriate port which I used to forward to the middleman from the remote server in the application with localhost and view the cameras. Unfortunately when I try to do something like this, I've been unable to make success or figure what my problem is.
I can clarify even further if possible; however, that will possibly confuse what my mission is.

Comment: `ssh -R 27013:... -R 27013:...` Well, binding two tunnels to the same port isn't going to work. Aside from that, I can't really tell what you're trying to set up here. Could you rewrite this to clarify what kind of forwarding you're trying to achieve?

Comment: oops! I meant to make one of those, in my question, 27014.